# Load balancer slowing down the site

Tags: php, apache, load-balancing

We have 6 web servers and a load balancer in between.

But load balancing seems to actually slowing down the things. If I access the site using any server's IP address the site gets opened fast compared to accessing through load balancer.

On load balancer it seems requests wait for long till they get response from other requests, especially for JS code. Load balancer is configured with session affinity though.
Some times there are even redirect loops. On certain networks the response doesn't come at all leaving the site broken.

Are there any tips that I need to follow. How to know if load balancer is configured and working properly?

Load balancer is on apache and site is built using PHP.

**UPDATE**:
Load balancing is done through LVS and the algorithm used is Round-Robin scheduling.
I am not sure what other details are required, but the problem is, when I access the site directly using any one server's IP address, it comes fine and pretty fast, but, when I use load balancer IP address, some resources like css/images don't load at all and site keeps loading for long time and then eventually fails.
I tried with all IP addresses of all servers and all work fine, seems like there is a problem with LB, just not sure how to know. Let me know if I am missing any crucial info again to know the problem exactly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of load balancing software/hardware are you using?  Apache doesn't load balance.  Software like Linux Virtual Server (LVS) or hardware Load Balancers like F5s

Comment: Is there any way to find this without contacting the provider?

Comment: You'd need to contact your provider unless using a packet tracing tool or vewing the HTTP headers reveal information about your load balancer.

Comment: Agreed. Any number of things could be wrong here, and without more information, it's almost impossible to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. Load balancing is done through LVS and the algorithm used is Round-Robin scheduling.
I am not sure what other details are required, but the problem is, when I access the site directly using any one server's IP address, it comes fine and pretty fast, but, when I use load balancer IP address, some resources like css/images don't load at all and site keeps loading for long time and then eventually fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found out the reason here.

It is nothing to do with load balancer. I pinged the nameservers and found out many packets were getting lost.

Now have increased the ttl, hoping it will resolve the issue else going to have own nameservers.

Thanks